# Firefox OS Architecture

Tags: operating-system, firefox-os

Is there any information available on the core architecture of the Firefox OS? I don't mean developer-facing information only. I am interested in the underlying architecture similar to that of Android available here: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-android-works-the-big-picture/515

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In few words, Firefox OS is an environment where running HTML5-based applications (not only the mark-up language but all associated technologies including JavaScript, CSS3, web APIs...).

These applications run on an special browser called Gecko. You can consider Gecko as a Firefox with steroids with applications replacing web pages. In some aspects it lacks of some browser functionality but it implements a lot of APIs to provide a safe access to the devices.

Gecko is supported by the actual SO, Gonk. Gonk is a very simple distribution of GNU/Linux and it holds the Hardware Abstraction Layer or HAL placed between the device hardware and Gecko. Gonk translates low level hardware access to C++ interfaces and Gecko offers these interfaces to developers in form of JavaScript standard APIs.

More info in [Mozilla Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/B2G/Architecture)

Answer (score 7):

It is mainly Gonk (underlying linux kernel), Gecko (Firefox engine) and Gaia (user interface). On the Mozilla wiki you can find the full info on these layers; [Mozilla wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/B2G/Architecture)

Answer (score 1):

The main Firefox OS architecture is

- Application ([Gaia](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia))
- Platform ([Gecko](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central))
- Infrastructure ([Gonk](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/B2G))

There's a [Overview and High Level Architecture](http://www.mozilla-hispano.org/archivos/docs/fxosappdaysvall/arquitectura.pdf)  slide(english) from Firefox OS AppDay in Spanish that elaborate the Architecture more concisely.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below link for full Firefox OS architecture along with security information:

[Click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Security/Security_model)

Answer (score 0):

On MDN you'll find a very similar image that explains exactly how Firefox OS works:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Platform/Architecture